How can I use an op-amp in differential configuration to measure voltage across a MOSFET?
I want to use an opamp in a differential configuration to measure the voltage at the drain and source terminals of a mosfet.
The mosfet will have a maximum of 400Vds across it.
I cannot find an opamp that can handle 400V at its inputs, so my current approach is to use a voltage divider to step down the voltage to a range suitable for the opamp inputs.
However, I am worried this is not the most optimal approach.
Is there a better solution, that will result in better measurements and not interfere with the rest of the circuit the mosfet is attached to?

What is the MOSFET controlling - I.e. what is the "rest of the circuit" and how sensitive is it? How much current is it passing? Is it on/off control? PWM? Linear? What are your requirements for CMRR, noise, frequency response, bandwidth, distortion? Where is the signal going?

This looks like an X-Y problem.

Are you in fact trying to detect desaturation of a high-side switching MOSFET?

@vir The mosfet is being used to switch PWM. I don't care too much about CMRR, or noise. I just need a solution that won't preturb the circuit the mosfet is being used in too much.

You can use a classic differential amplifier, as long as you keep the op-amp's inputs within its common-mode limits:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This relies on R1 and R3 to provide high input impedance, while establishing op-amp inverting and non-inverting input potentials well within the supply potentials of ±5V.
Assuming \$R_1=R_3\$ and \$R_2=R_4\$, differential gain is \$\frac{R_4}{R_3}=0.005\$, so using the values shown, a full scale input of \$V_{IN+} - V_{IN-}=\pm 400V\$ will result in an output of \$V_{OUT}=\pm 2.0V\$.
In practice you should distribute the high potential across several input resistors, and provide some clamping, just in case:

simulate this circuit

You should add (if necessary) also capacitors on 2 MOhm resistors and 50 kOhm for transient behavior.

@Antonio51: Capacitors to ground? (otherwise parasitic capacitance across the resistors could momentarily have +400VDC on the op-amp inputs when IN+ changes from 0V to +400V nearly instantly?)  A small capacitor in parallel with R2 sounds like a good idea, for an RC time constant of maybe a millisecond or something if you're trying to measure DC?  (edit: the OP says they want to measure things like voltage ripple, with minimal perturbation presumably including when the probe is first attached.)

No. One capacitor paralleled with one resistor ... it is the same idea that "compensated attenuators". the product of Rx*Cx (Cx paralleled with Rx) must be constant. So R1a * C1a = R1b * C1b = ... = R2  * C2. Same for R2a ... R4. C1a ... C1e may be low (some pF). So, R1a * C1a = 2 MOhm * 10 pF = ... = R2 * 400 pF. And the whole system is "independent" of the frequency.

Here is what I meant : https://i.sstatic.net/FyRIySwV.png for  300pF < C5 < 500 pF.

Until you said 400 V the right answer was probably an instrumentation amplifier/ op amp.
But 400 V plus the need to not disturb the circuit means much more information is needed. Are you measuring DC or transients, and if transients how fast? What resistance AND parallel capacitance is allowed without disturbing the circuit? What kind of accuracy in rejecting the common mode is needed? Etc.
My first thought without knowing any more is two high voltage probes connected to an oscilloscope used to do A-B subtraction.
My second thought is to ask whether you really need to do what you are asking. If the objective is to trouble-shoot a circuit there may be better (although maybe not straightforward) solutions.

I need to build a circuit to do this, as I am building a device to test power circuit topologies. I want to measure transients. I don't require fast measuring speeds, I just need them to be fast enough to calculate things like voltage ripple.

I'm shooting for as minimal perturbation to the circuit as possible.

If it helps, the mosfet will exclusively be used to switch PWM signals.

@MXVG "as minimal as possible" is not an engineering spec. The more time and money you throw into it the more you'll improve it (with diminishing gains ofc), but only you know what "good enough" is.

Assuming the S is ground, you can protect the opamp's other input from high V by:
A) connect to the D with a R and use a low V zener to gnd. The zener will clamp the opamps V to a safe value.
Or
B) use another HV FET. This can be small (don't care about resistance); connect the drains together; gate to a few V (maybe 5), and put a zener from S to GND. Make the zener V higher than the gate V
This will pass the main FET D voltage through the aux FET as long as D is low. When D is high, the output (S) won't be more than the zener V
